# React Fabric UI Pivot unmounts component on PivotItem change

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I'm using a Pivot component from FabricUI but I'm stuck because I have several PivotItems and every PivotItem has a child component that talks to the server when it's mounted. Every time I change a pivot item, current component get's unmounted and a new one is mounted.

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem linkText='One' itemKey='0'>
       <GridDataOne/>  
    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem linkText='Two' itemKey='1'>
        <GridDataTwo/>  
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>

class GridDataTwo extends React.Component<any,any> {
   ...
   componentDidMount() {
       fetchDataFromServer()...
   }
}
```

How can I avoid this kind of behaviour? Is it possible to hide unactive pivot items rather then unmounting it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make the call to the server from the `Pivot`'s `onLinkClick` callback as in [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/658aacf829d240008ab1b387d0a6ce46583f8b76/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Pivot/Pivot.types.ts#L61). It will pass you back the `PivotItem`. If you set the `itemKey` prop on each `PivotItem` you can then know exactly what tab is about to render and then decide what specific call to make based on that id. You can see an example of that [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Pivot/examples/Pivot.Separate.Example.tsx).

Unfortunately, there is no way to hide the unselected tabs as this would mean having them all loaded on the page and who knows how many of them are there and how heavy they are.

Comment: I'm using headerOnly mode in Pivot and keeping every component mounted in DOM and showin/hidinig just the ones I need based on PivotItem itemKey.. I'm not expieriencing any performace issues, yet :)

Comment: @partyelite Excellent hint, I'm also doing this now successfully. Party on!

Comment: @partyelite do you have any sample code? i'm trying to do similar thanks